Can I transfer the files on other account to free up some space in Google Drive?
I read that there is a transfer of ownership in Google Drive but it seems it will not free up the space on the original owner, is the ownership transfer only works on access level?

The question premise is wrong. Please add the source or provide more details about how to construct it. In other words, show what you have tried.

By the way, it might take up to 24 hours for the storage quota usage meter to update.

Can you [edit] your post and elaborate on what you mean by "it will not free up the space on the original owner, is the ownership transfer only works on access level"?
